# Can wso2 data service return affected rows after SQL update?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I have used WSO2 Data service to connect to DB for while. All are perfect except that I still couldn't get the affected rows after a SQL update script.

I've go through the wizard and try again and again, and found no solution.

Is there anyone know how to get it?

Thanks any kindly reply in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid, there isn't a way to get the updated row count directly, but a possibly work-around would be to wrap your update statements in a stored procedure, and from the stored procedure return the row count as the result, maybe as an OUT parameter.

Cheers,
Anjana.

Comment: Now, from DSS v3.5.0, you have this functionality built-in, please check https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS350/Adding+Input+Mappings#AddingInputMappings-Returningupdatedrowcount.